# fetching a page using curl - in php it works fine but when i use ajax there is an issue

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I have a php page that curl the following address. it retrieve the page run some xpath queries and returns / echos the results.

When i access this page through the browser it works fine no error is being displayed and the results are being returned.

However when i try to access this page through ajax nothing returns to ajax and it seems like it somewhat stuck.

the flow of event is: i do ajax call to my php page. In that page i do the crul and xpath query and the results are being returned to ajax.

This is the page i try to retrieve.

http://www.zara.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/us/en/zara-us-W2012-s/337006/908067/FANTASY%20MINI%20SKIRT%20WITH%20DIAMANTE

Whats weird is php doesn't through any error I've set `error_reporting (-1);` to show all errors just incase and still Nothing

here is how i do the curl call:

```
$url = 'http://www.zara.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/us/en/zara-us-W2012-s/337006/908067/FANTASY%20MINI%20SKIRT%20WITH%20DIAMANTE';

$pageData = curl_init($url);
$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13";
curl_setopt($pageData, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($pageData, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($pageData, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    // - update
    // echo "notification";
    // exit;
    //
echo $to_return = curl_exec($pageData);
```

This is the ajax call:

```
var ajax_url = 'http://www.somedomain.com/f/ajax_func.php';
var url_to_search = 'http://www.zara.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/us/en/zara-us-W2012-s/337006/908067/FANTASY%20MINI%20SKIRT%20WITH%20DIAMANTE';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_url,
    data: { ajax_search_product: "ajax", url_to_search: url_to_search}
    }).success(function(data) {
        alert(data);
})
```

Am i missing soemthing ? this is really awkward how comes in php it works but as ajax it causes an unexplained error

Comment: What about the ajax code?

Comment: i can supply it but its pretty standard

Comment: Try using a relative URL for ajax_url.

Comment: Your ajax url has no HTTP too.

Comment: i wish the issue was that simple. the url works this was just an example sorry for forgetting the HTTP

Comment: Can you tell us what is happening when you run the page? What error is being shown in the console (if any)?

Comment: None in console none in php

Comment: If you are using chrome and you go into the network tab of the developers console can you watch when the request goes through and tell us what response do you see? Also, are you triggering the $.ajax()?

Comment: using FF and firebug but did not see any error i will check now. the error is 99% somewhere around `curl_exec($pageData);
` simply because when i stop the script before this call and echo something ajax do receive what i echoed

Comment: Are you eventually echoing/printing $to_return?

Comment: respond is empty and is i actually echo $to_return but it doesnt do anything

Comment: Can you `echo curl_error($pageData)` after the execution?

Comment: I've made a little update to the page - the if i un comment those 2 lines.. i will get the word notification back in ajax.

Comment: eching curl_error - echoed nothing - and i dont really echo the whole page that i fetch. i json_encode and array of information that i create using xpath->queries of the page i retrieved.  so the way i am echoing is not the problem its something much more complicated or weird

Comment: Perhaps try setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `0` to see if it prints. Without seeing exactly what you're doing, with your actual code, it could be something else.

Comment: well there isn't much to it the rest of the code is irrelevant. and the simple fact that when i echo something and exit before the curl execute means the problem must be within  around the curl - nothing else

Comment: Then can you show us before CURL? It looks like you are using the `$_POST['url_to_search']` in your actual code (based on your ajax request). If this is the case, can you see if `echo $_POST['url_to_search']` returns anything?

Comment: Thank you very much for you help johnmadrak I've found the issue with your last comment. the issue was i was an idiot and did not `encodeurlcomponenet()` the url and that cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add error function in your ajax to know what the status and error is...

error:function(xhr,err){
alert("ERROR : "+err);
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
}
```